# Expression.Lamda is not working with dynamically generated class

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, lambda, expression-trees

Here is sample code do test:

```
var assembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("asm"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var builder = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
Type type = builder.DefineType("newType");
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type);
Console.WriteLine(type);
var expr = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(1), parameter);
```

Here I get an exception

> Specified method is not supported

How can I avoid it? I don't have this type an compile-time, and I want to create a constructor by using `Expression`s instead of Emitting it manually. Is it even possible? I did it with instance methods, but I did it without using `this`. Now I need it, but access to type if forbidden while it is under construction.

Comment: You are missing `var finalType = builder.CreateType();` Have a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38389479/reflection-emit-throws-badimageformatexception/38389729?noredirect=1#comment64189813_38389729)

Comment: It's not a final type. How could I add a constructor after I freeze the class?

Comment: After you defined your new class you have to Create it in order to get a valid type. If you want to add another contructor, do something like this `builder.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public, CallingConventions.HasThis, new[] { typeof(string) });` No overload accepts an expression

Comment: then I want to use `Expression` to generate constructor's body. As I said it works fine until I'm not touching `this` members, with `Expression.CompileToMethod` method.

Comment: It's an infinite loop: I can't freeze a class before I generate methods, and I cannot generate methods before I freeze a class (becuase I get an exception above).

Comment: As far as I know, `CompileToMethod()` cannot be used to compile constructors anyway.

Comment: @svick it doesn't work for instance method as well, but with a little tramplin everything is possible. I don't think that differs for constructor. But it seems that I found a solution, I'm working on it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found an elegant workaround for this.

- Firstly, we just create a base class, in my case it was:

  ```
  public abstract class AsyncClientBase
  {
      protected readonly IAsyncRequestProcessor Processor;

      protected AsyncClientBase(IAsyncRequestProcessor processor)
      {
          Processor = processor;
      }
  }
  ```
- Then we can use fields in our expressions (because base type is
  already builded).
- Then we use Emit to create pass-params constructors
  ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879279/using-typebuilder-to-create-a-pass-through-constructor-for-the-base-class) is an example)
- Finally, we just change type `T` of `this` parameter in methods on `T`'s base type (there is an implicit conversion child -> base, so that's ok), and we are able to use fields in our generated methods.

[Here](https://github.com/Pzixel/WcfRestClient/tree/master/WcfRestClient) is a complete code (see `ServiceClient`, `Helpers.XLambdaExpression`, `Helper.EmitHelper`).